# Angular StackBlitz error: [NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'write$1' on null]

Tags: angular, angular-material, stackblitz

I am trying to setup a [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bfwgw?file=src/theming.scss) with Angular Material theming, following [the official guide for Angular Material 11 theming](https://v11.material.angular.io/guide/theming).

I created a sass file for the custom theme configuration `theming.scss`, but when I try to import it into the global `styles.scss` file I get the following error in StackBlitz:

```
Error in src/styles.scss
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'write$1' on null
```

The project doesn't run, you can test it from the link above, can you tell me what is wrong my configuration? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem**

Today I opened an old project that I'm sure worked fine. I got the same error.

That's how I found this question ...

I think the problem is the **builder under the hood**.

I think it **doesn't use versions of Angular and Sass matching your package.json**.

**The solution**

The way to bypass entirely the issue is using a **webcontainer** version (the recent Node.js project) of stackblitz.
That way it compiles using your real dependencies.
Here's a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-angular-13-web-container-starter) you can fork